# How do I know who I slept with?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I have an ME1 save, but no longer have access to the game itself. I wish to start a new game in ME2 (Xbox 360) based on this save in preparation for ME3.

I haven't started the playthrough yet and am wondering how I can tell who I had a romance with in ME1? This will determine how I will make my romantic decisions in both ME2 and ME3.

Comment: The eternal question

Comment: I have this problem all the time. What I normally do is- Oh, wait, you're talking about Mass Effect. Never mind.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Once you gain access to the Normandy SR-2, take a peek around Shepard's personal quarters.

If you had a love interest in Mass Effect 1, Shep will have a framed picture of them on zer desk.

If you then go on to romance someone else, Shep will tactfully... place the picture face down.

Comment: If you do that twice, in ME3 will you have two face-down pictures and one normal one?

Comment: @BenBrocka Nah. No one in ME3 particularly cares if you go separate ways.

Comment: Very good solution :D.

Comment: @RavenDreamer `Thon` is the best gender-neutral pronoun!

Comment: Actually it looks like Thon is male: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Thon

Comment: @Callum Zer is in the same vein as singular their and eir -- it's a gender-neutral pronoun. Unlike singular their, however, it's not widely accepted.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't started the playthrough yet, it *should* tell you on the import screen (along with the other major decisions that you made.

Otherwise, as Raven Dreamer said, you can always look at the picture.

Comment: Is it mentioned on the ME2 import? I thought it was just in ME3, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You could always poke around the save file with a [save-game editor](http://www.moddb.com/games/mass-effect-2/downloads/mass-effect-2-save-editor).

As a bonus, this will let you change who you romanced, if you want to.

Comment: I didn't mention that this is the x360 version :)

Comment: @JamesJiao There's a save editor for the xbox aswell

Comment: @Serge Really? Where do I find it and how do I install it... if you don't mind me being nosy?

Comment: @James Jiao - You need a device that lets you read the xbox save files on a computer (I'm not sure how they work). Anyways, get the software [here](http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/gibbeds-mass-effect-2-save-editor.156047/)

Comment: i want to add though it only works for mass effect 2 save files. So you should import your mass effect 1 save file first and then save the game as soon as you can and open/edit it with the editor.